# JavaScript Password Validation not working

Tags: javascript

I am using this for my password matching but it is not working can anyone edit it please

```
 <html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">
function validateFormOnSubmit(theForm) {
var reason = "";

reason += validatePassword(theForm.pw1);

if (reason != "") {
    alert("Some fields need correction:\n" + reason);
    return false;
  }

  alert("All fields are filled correctly");
  return false;
}

function validatePassword(fld) {
    var error = "";
    var illegalChars = /[\W_]/; // allow only letters and numbers 

    if (fld.value == "") {
        fld.style.background = 'Yellow';
        error = "You didn't enter a Password.\n";
    } else if ((fld.value.length < 3) || (fld.value.length > 15)) {
        error = "The Password is the wrong length. \n";
        fld.style.background = 'Yellow';
    } else if (illegalChars.test(fld.value)) {
        error = "The Password contains illegal characters.\n";
        fld.style.background = 'Yellow';
    } else if (!((fld.value.search(/(a-z)+/)) && (fld.value.search(/(0-9)+/)))) {
        error = "The Password must contain at least one numeral.\n";
        fld.style.background = 'Yellow';
    } else {
        fld.style.background = 'White';
    }
   return error;

}  
function trim(s)
{
  return s.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/, '');
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form onsubmit="return validateFormOnSubmit(this)" >

<table border=0>
  <tr>
    <td><label for="pw1">Password:</label></td>
    <td><input type="password" name="pw1" size="20" id="password" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label for="pw2">Confirm Password:</label></td>
    <td><input type="password" name="pw2" size="20" id="confPassword" /></td>
  </tr>
<tr>
<td colspan=2 align=center><input type=submit value="Submit!"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

its working but i want to match the password also . but i am unable to do that how can do it?

Comment: What's "not working"? Do you get an error? Does it not work as expected? If so, what does happen?

Comment: @James Allardice :) password validation in javascript i m using but this condition does not meet the requirement ...

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/n9mL4/. You don't have a starting `<html>` though.

Comment: @smithjohn: In that case please elaborate on the 'requirement'.

Comment: @pimvdb :)i want to match the password like if pw1=pw2 then okk otherwise alert

Comment: You are not doing any **password matching** as you say in the starting line.Other validations are working fine

Comment: @anu :) want to add password validation also in this how it is possible ? all things keep remain same some litle changes only i want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add another check and pass the second password box as well: http://jsfiddle.net/n9mL4/1/.

```
validatePassword(theForm.pw1, theForm.pw2);
```

and

```
... } else if(fld.value != fld2.value) {
    error = "Not equal.";
    fld.style.background = "Yellow";
    fld2.style.background = "Yellow";
} else { ...
```